# Instance of class in window.opener from popup window

Tags: jquery, popup, instance

I have a window from which I click a popup window, for example

```
<td class="links" onclick="openPopUp()">*view profile*</a>
```

I have about 10 class with the same name, how can I change the text in the clicked class from *the popup window*?

This works from within the same page `$(this).siblings(".links").text("whatever");` but not from popup. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this...

**Page 1: Parent.html**

Java Script :

```
   <script language="JavaScript">
        function getData(txt1,txt2,txt3){
           $("tr td:nth-child(1)").text(txt1)
           $("tr td:nth-child(2)").text(txt2)
           $("tr td:nth-child(3)").text(txt3)
           msgWindow.close();
        }

        function openPopUp(file, window)
        {
            msgWindow = open(file, window, 'scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,width=550,height=400');
            if (msgWindow.opener == null)
                msgWindow.opener = self;
        }
    </script>
```

HTML :

```
  <body>
    <form name="parentForm" >
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td class="links" onclick="openPopUp('Popup.html', 'window2')">*view profile 1*</a></td>                 
                <td class="links" onclick="openPopUp('Popup.html', 'window2')">*view profile 2*</a></td>                  
                <td class="links" onclick="openPopUp('Popup.html', 'window2')">*view profile 3*</a></td>   
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

**Page 2 : Popup.html**

HTML :

```
  <body>
    <form name="popupForm" >
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>Text1</td>                                   
                <td>Text2</td>                                  
                <td>Text3</td>                    
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <a href="javascript:void();" onclick="window.opener.getData($('tr td:nth-child(1)').text(),$('tr td:nth-child(2)').text(),$('tr td:nth-child(3)').text());return false;">Close</a>
</body>
```